# Ninject-ing Mehdime.Entity.IDbContextScopeFactory failing

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, ninject.web

I am trying make use of [Mehdi El Gueddari's DBContextScope solution](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/) and DI it into my WebAPI2 Controller as follows:

NinjectConfigurator.cs:

```
container.Bind<IUserProfileInquiryProcessor>().To<UserProfileInquiryProcessor>().InRequestScope();
container.Bind<IDbContextScopeFactory>().To<DbContextScopeFactory>().InSingletonScope();
```

UserProfileController.cs:

```
public UserProfileController(
    IUserProfileInquiryProcessor userProfileInquiryProcessor,
    IDbContextScopeFactory dbContextScopeFactory)
{
    _dbContextScopeFactory = dbContextScopeFactory;
    _userProfileInquiryProcessor = userProfileInquiryProcessor;
}
```

However, Ninject appears to be failing to inject `IDbContextScopeFactory` and returns with the following exception:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'UserProfileController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

I know it is `IDbContextScopeFactory` that is failing to resolve and the controller is created if I omit that parameter (only) from the constructor.

Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong or what I should try?  Thanks.